# How do i write a query to select the top and bottom 3 values from 2 tables using a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

A relational database contains 2 tables : books and authors, each containing over 1 million rows.

The tables are described as: 
Books (Title, Copies Sold) where Title is the primary key
Authors (Author, Title) where Title refers to Books

Write a SINGLE query that shows that top 3 authors and the bottom 3 authors based on the number of copies sold.

I am trying to work on this problem, however I have failed.

```
select *  
from authors a 
left  join books b on a.authortitle = b.title 
order by b.sold;
```

when I tried this, this is the response that I receive.

```
select *  
from authors a 
left  join books b on a.authortitle = b.title 
order by b.sold 
group by author;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'group by author' at line 1

I am not sure what it means. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: which mysql version you are using?

Comment: show sample data!!!its required!!

Comment: Does selling `0` copies count as the "least"?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **UNION** operator. Something like this ( this code is untested :D )

```
(select * from authors a left join books b on a.authortitle = b.title order by b.sold limit 3)
union
(select * from authors aa left join books bb on aa.authortitle = bb.title order by bb.sold desc limit 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*,
rank() over(partition by a.author order by b.copiessold asc) rk  
from authors a 
left  join books b on a.authortitle = b.title 
where rk<4
UNION ALL
select a.*,
rank() over(partition by a.author order by b.copiessold desc) rk  
from authors a 
left  join books b on a.authortitle = b.title 
where rk<4;
```

Comment: @DylanSee if that solveed your problem give it a green tick at left hand side!!!!